# change buttons backgroundcolor in awt

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

So i have a GUI program called Safe25. Basically, if you press the buttons in the right order which is "15032018" the program closes itself.
If you input a correct number, lets say you press 1 at the start, the buttons should change their backgroundcolor to green like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1hpt.png):

If you press a wrong button, the buttons should change their color to red.

But the logic of my code is irrelevant for my problem. 
As i said, i want to change the buttons backgroundcolor like in the linked image. My problem is that it changes the backgroundcolor of the frame instead like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvVFj.png)

The important line is 75, i commented this one.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Safe25 extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    JButton[] buttons;

    Safe25() { // Konstruktor
        setSize(250, 300); 
        setLocation(300, 300);
        setTitle("Safe25"); 

        buttons = new JButton[10]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // 10 Knöpfe im Array
            buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i); 
            buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 34));
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this); // 
        }

        Panel panel0 = new Panel(); 
        panel0.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1)); 
        panel0.add(buttons[0]); 
        Panel panelRest = new Panel(); 
        panelRest.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3)); 
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1)); 
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 
            panelRest.add(buttons[i]); 
        }
        add(panel0); // Panel mit 0-Knopf
        add(panelRest); 
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent wv) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    int s = 0; 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 Zustände ...
        // 1-5-0-3-2-0-1-8 ist richtige Kombination
        switch (Integer.parseInt(evt.getActionCommand())) {
        case 0:
            s = (s == 2 || s == 5) ? s + 1 : 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            s = (s == 0 || s == 6) ? s + 1 : 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            s = (s == 4) ? s + 1 : 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            s = (s == 3) ? s + 1 : 0;
            break;
        case 5:
            s = (s == 1) ? s + 1 : s == 7 ? 2 : 0;
            break;
        case 8:
            s = (s == 7) ? s + 1 : 0;
            break;
        default:
            s = 0;
        }
        Color col;
        if (s == 0) { 
            col = Color.red;
        } else { // richtiger Weg
            col = Color.green;
        }
        if (s == 8) { 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (Component c : getComponents()) // line 75, i want this one
            c.setBackground(col); // to change the buttons backgroundcolor
        repaint(); // but it changes the frames backgroundcolor instead
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Safe25 we = new Safe25();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you red the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) for JButton?

edit:

Sorry i looked over your code to quickly. What your doing right now is setting the background color of every component in the current container. 
While your buttons array is global you could simply loop trough that collection again to get the correct components "the buttons" and setting the background color like so:

```
        for (JButton b : buttons) // line 75, i want this one
           b.setBackground(col); // to change the buttons backgroundcolor
        repaint(); // but it changes the frames backgroundcolor instead
```

Comment: It seems like setBackground is buggy for me. If i replace setBackground with setForeground in the code your given me, everything works as it should. If i use setBackground tho, just nothing happens, everything stays white. I also tested this in another class, still the same problem. I gave a friend of mine the code and it works for him, so its only buggy on my end, only with the setBackground method, the setForeground method works fine. I´m using a mac with the newest eclipse version, so i´m not sure what causes that bug

Comment: `setBackground` is a bound property, it should trigger a repaint on it's own

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, no, not really - or at least not as you might expect.

The button's content is provided by the look and feel delegate, most of which ignore things like the `background` property (or at least don't use it in ways you might think it should).

Instead, you need to remove these decorations and do a little of the work yourself

For example...

```
buttons = new JButton[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // 10 Knöpfe im Array
    buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
    buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 34));
    buttons[i].setContentAreaFilled(false);
    buttons[i].setOpaque(true);
    buttons[i].setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    buttons[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
    buttons[i].addActionListener(this); // 
}
```

This disables the area filling, replaces the border and makes the component transparent, which produces something along the lines of

[image: Custom Button background]